# Neo4j Client connection URL

Tags: c#, neo4j

I have the following neo4j server running on localhost, and I cannot figure out what the Uri string should be:

My database location is: "c:\users...\Documents\Neo4j\tutorial.graphdb"

My status says "Neo4j is ready. Browse to http://localhost:7474/"

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data/tutorial.graphdb"));
        client.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

Browser works at: "http://localhost:7474/browser/"

Comment: The url for the connection is http://localhost:7474/db/data

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response :). Tried that and it tells me that no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. I also tried "localhost:7474/db/data/tutorial" with the same result

Comment: If you use neo4j 2.2.x then you should authenticate your requests with a username and password

Answer (score 0):

URI of connection string should include username and password.

So your code should look like this :

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"),"neo4j","password");
        client.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```